# Is $\phi^4$ theory unstable?

Tags: field-theory, computational-physics, simulations, interactions, stability

I tried to write a simulation of a $\phi^4$ [theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_interaction) for 2+1 dimensions. But whatever values I gave for the coupling constant it always seems to blow up.

i.e. a wave-like equation with a mass and quartic term. The equations of motion become

$$\partial^2 \phi + m^2 \phi + \lambda \phi^3 = 0$$

Is such an equation inherantly unstable?

I am interested in what a self-interacting non-linear wave equation behaves like in the classical sense.

Comment: How exactly does it blow up? The Wikipedia page you link to has some exact solutions in terms of Jacobi elliptic functions, which do seem tame.

Comment: @Ruslan These are exact solutions with very specific starting conditions. What I mean is that if you start of with random values of the fields, is it likely that the fields go off to infinity. I will try my simulations again I guess.